# How to verify ILogger in .NetCore Unit Tesing by Moq?

Tags: c#, moq

I am trying to test the ILogger(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) in my project(.net core 3.1) by Moq, however...it failed..
I am trying to catch an exception in my code:

```
  try{
      //do something
     }
    catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(new
                {
                    RequestId = requestId.ToString(),
                    Topic = "Merge files",
                    Message = "process failed",
                    Status = "Failed"
                }, e);
            }
```

And I defined the mock logger

```
private readonly Mock<ILogger<MyClass>> _logger = new Mock<ILogger<MyClass>>();
```

here is my UT for this

```
_logger.Verify(
                x => x.Log(
                    It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
                    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                    It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((v, t) => true),
                    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                    It.Is<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>((v, t) => true)), Times.Once);
```

I debugged it, the log exception method is executed in my code, but at last the UT is failed as I get following message:

> Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x =>
> x.Log<It.IsAnyType>(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny(),
> It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((v, t) => True), It.IsAny(),
> It.Is<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>((v, t) => True))

Comment: Unless you have _made your own logger_, why would you want to test a first class logger from Microsoft?  Let alone mock it

Comment: In the catch block you are calling LogError method on Logger and you are mocking Log method in the UT.

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't look like you've posted a working example; I assume your anonymous object is your log message and you're using a native LogError extension rather than your own, which will mean the exception parameter will need to come before the anonymous object (which would also probably need to be converted to a string).

Anyway with that addressed the Verify expression you have provided does work when tested. LINQPad example:

```
void Main()
{
    var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<Foo>>();
    var logger = loggerMock.Object;
    var requestId = Guid.NewGuid();

    try
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Bar");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, new
        {
            RequestId = requestId.ToString(),
            Topic = "Merge files",
            Message = "process failed",
            Status = "Failed"
        }.ToString());
    }

    loggerMock.Verify(
                x => x.Log(
                    It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
                    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                    It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((v, t) => true),
                    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                    It.Is<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>((v, t) => true)), Times.Once); 
}

public class Foo
{

}
```

[image]

Change to Times.Never and it fails as expected:

[image]

Is your test invoking that block of code in your SUT?

Some additional suggestions:

It's better practice to use [placeholders in your log message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#log-message-template):

```
logger.LogError(ex, "Process failed; requestId: '{requestId}', topic: '{topic}', status: '{status}'", requestId.ToString(), "Merge files", "Failed");
```

Logged values (which can be objects if that suits) can then be parsed by your log aggregator.

Asserting log invocations can be a pain, there are a couple of libraries around that make it a bit easier. [Moq.Contrib.ExpressionBuilders.Logging](https://github.com/rgvlee/Moq.Contrib.ExpressionBuilders.Logging) is one that I wrote specifically because of this:

```
logger.Verify(Log.With.LogLevel(LogLevel.Error)
                .And.LogMessage("Process failed; requestId: '{requestId}', topic: '{topic}', status: '{status}'")
                .And.LoggedValue("requestId", requestId.ToString())
                .And.LoggedValue("topic", "Merge files")
                .And.LoggedValue("status", "Failed")
                .And.ExceptionMessage("Bar"),
            Times.Once);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's very helpful to me. And I did a deep research, may find why.

Answer (score 1):

I did a deep research about this.

In my project, my LogError() method invokes another Define() method in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to do the log operations.

By this method logic, I have to mock the logger.IsEnabled(logLevel) first.

```
_logger.Setup(x => x.IsEnabled(It.IsAny<LogLevel>())).Returns(true);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you need to setup the LogError method on the mock.
Alternatively, you could setup a callback on the LogError method, capture the error, and then assert.